# How to store websockets at the server side with aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, aiohttp

I'm trying to make simple web-chat with rooms using aiohttp. Can you please advise me how to store my websockets connections? Some code below are simplified a bit. I'm getting an EOF error from socket time by time (and I can reproduce it), but i don't know why. So, i got a question, am i do it right? Should i close websockets everytime when i reload or follow to link? If not, so, how i will connect client with my already opened socket? Sorry for my eng ^^ thanks.

app.py

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2
import hashlib
import collections
import os
from aiohttp_session import session_middleware
from aiohttp_session.cookie_storage import EncryptedCookieStorage
from aiohttp import web

from routes import routes
from middlewares import authorize
from motor import motor_asyncio as ma
from settings import *


basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
photo_dir = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/photo/')

async def on_shutdown(app):
    for ws in app['websockets']:
        await ws.close(code=1001, mesage='Server shutdown')

middle = [
    session_middleware(EncryptedCookieStorage(hashlib.sha256(bytes(SECRET_KEY, 'utf-8')).digest())),
    authorize
]

app = web.Application(middlewares=middle)

aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'))

for route in routes:
    app.router.add_route(*route[:3], name=route[3])
app['static_root_url'] = '/static'
app.router.add_static('/static', 'static', name='static')

app.client = ma.AsyncIOMotorClient(MONGO_HOST)
app.db = app.client[MONGO_DB_NAME]

app.on_cleanup.append(on_shutdown)
app['websockets'] = collections.defaultdict(list)
app['online'] = {}
app['photo_dir'] = photo_dir

web.run_app(app)
```

and websocket handler

```py
class CompanyWebSocket(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        await ws.prepare(self.request)

        session = await get_session(self.request)
        self_id = session.get('user')
        login = session.get('login')
        company_id = self.request.rel_url.query.get('company_id')
        message = Message(self.request.app.db)
        company = Company(self.request.app.db)
        my_companys = await company.get_company_by_user(self_id)

        for c in my_companys:
            self.request.app['websockets'][str(c['_id'])].append(ws)

        async for msg in ws:
            if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
                if msg.data == 'close':
                    await ws.close()

                else:
                    await message.save_for_company({'data': 'data'})
                    mess = {
                        'data': 'data'
                    }
                    # send mess to users in company
                    for company_ws in self.request.app['websockets'][company_id]:
                        await company_ws.send_json(mess)

            elif msg.type == WSMsgType.ERROR:
                log.debug('ws connection closed with exception %s' % ws.exception())

        try:
            self.request.app['websockets'][company_id].remove(ws)
        except:
            pass
        for _ws in self.request.app['websockets'][company_id]:
            await _ws.send_json({'user': login, 'type': 'left'})

        return ws
```